# How to enable Paging inside Winforms web browser WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, browser, paging

i have a Winforms web browser that read local xhtml files (related to EPUB File) .
Sometimes, a chapter in the book is too long .
i would like to disable scroll bar , and enable paging .
(example : A xhtml page with 100 unity vertical length , will be displayed in 4 pages of 25 unity vertical length)

Example :

[image: Reading xhtml page in many pages without using Vertical scrollbar]

**EDIT :**

```
            <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="formsBrowser" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

My winforms browser is implement in my WPF project ( `using System.Windows.Forms` )

In my Code Behind :

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //initialise the windows.forms browser component
            Browser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
            {
                //disable the default context menu
                IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false
            };
            //put the browser control in the windows forms host
            formsBrowser.Child = Browser;
            Browser.Url = new Uri(@"C:\Users\Youssef\Desktop\MyDirectory\NoBookAvailable.html");
            myTreeview.SelectedItemChanged += myTreeview_SelectedItemChanged;
            Browser.Document.Click += Document_Click;

        }
```

Comment: With what code do you have problems and why is [wpf] tagged? You're using WinForms right? You should be more specific about what you don't understand with a code example of what you tried.

Comment: try [FlowDocumentPageViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentpageviewer(v=vs.110).aspx), may you load your document, rest is already in place.

Comment: i've tried it using `<BlockUIContainer>` but you have no idea how muck it makes it slow as a project !

Comment: even when using `<BlockUIContainer>` on the `FlowDocumentPageViewer` , it still show the web browser on a single page , because the scrollbar belongs to the browser , besides , it bugs a lot !